# How to compress dynamic code in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello guys can anyone help me with compressing of dynamic code in html5, css3 and php ?

Comment: What do you mean with `compress`?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic code?

Comment: what do you mean by code?

Comment: What do you mean by help?

Comment: I mean when you view page source in a page there is no white space

Comment: like this T_T http://codecanyon.net/item/dynamic-website-compressor/2838376

Comment: Then you need to minify your source code, just google it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is useless for PHP "code" as it runs on the server side.

For html, css, javascript, you can install [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) and some specialized plugins for your tasks like [gulp-minify-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) for minifying css and [gulp-minify-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-html) for minifying html for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you made any effort like doing a Google search, you should have found [this](http://davidwalsh.name/php-output-buffers):

```
<?php
    /*  start the output buffer  */
    ob_start('compress_page');

    /*  xhtml code below  */
?>
<!-- all xhtml content here -->
<?php
    /*  end the buffer, echo the page content  */
    ob_end_flush();

    /*  function that gets rid of tabs, line breaks, and extra spaces  */
    function compress_page($buffer) {
        $search = array('/>[^S ]+/s', '/[^S ]+</s', '/(s)+/s');
        $replace = array('>', '<', '1');
        return preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
    }
?>
```

As others have pointed out, you may use a task runner to minify your CSS and JS.

Meanwhile, your question is wrongly tagged as it has no relations with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot . working on HTML AND JS only

Comment: If it worked for you or lead you to the solution then you should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php

        /*  start the output buffer  */
        ob_start('compress_page');

        /*  xhtml code below  */
          /*  end the buffer, echo the page content  */
        ob_end_flush('compress_page');

        /*  function that gets rid of tabs, line breaks, and extra spaces  */
        function compress_page($buffer) {
                // remove comments, tabs, spaces, newlines, etc.
                $search = array(
                    "/\/\*(.*?)\*\/|[\t\r\n]/s" => "",
                    "/ +\{ +|\{ +| +\{/" => "{",
                    "/ +\} +|\} +| +\}/" => "}",
                    "/ +: +|: +| +:/" => ":",
                    "/ +; +|; +| +;/" => ";",
                    "/ +, +|, +| +,/" => ","
                );
                $buffer = preg_replace(array_keys($search), array_values($search), $buffer);
                return $buffer;
        }
    ?>
```

and Finally worked ^_^

Comment: man, you've got very little scruples :)